# Raise SystemExit not working

Tags: python-2.7

This is a simplified version of a portion of my program:

```
for i in range(5):

turn1l = []
turn1 = raw_input("Enter Value Using the format \'x,y\' : ")
turn1l.append(turn1)

def winnerchecker():
    if "1,1" in turn1l and "1,2" in turn1l and "1,3" in turn1l:
        print xplayer, "YOU HAVE WON! GG TO ", name
        raise SystemExit()
winnerchecker()
```

For some reason every time I enter "1,1" then "1,2" then "1,3" it doesn't stop the porgram, it keeps going. How do I get it to stop, is there any way I'm not aware of? Thank you!

Comment: Please fix the indentation. If you paste your code into the form, select the code, and click the `{ }` button, the code will be formatted properly (with the original indentation).

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reinitialize the list `turn1l` at the beginning of every iteration of the loop:

```
for i in range(5):
    turn1l = []
```

Instead, make the list once:

```
turn1l = []
for i in range(5):
    ...
```